# Allocating memory for triple pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

The function `somefunction()` takes a triple pointer as an argument.

```
int somefunction(tchar ***returnErrors);
```

How to allocate memory for the `returnErrors` parameter?

Comment: What should the function do? Do you have documentation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At a guess . . .*

You can think of returnErrors as a pointer to an array of strings.

1. The first * imples pointer to array
   of tchar (or a single string of
   tchars)
2. The second * imples a pointer to an
   array of strings.
3. The last * is so you can change
   returnErrors and pass back the new
   memory.

To delare memory for this (silly example, allocating memory inside SomeFunction)

```
tchar ** errors;
// Oops it appears I need to pass back two error strings (+ 1 for null on end, so we know there are no more - thanks tlholaday)
errors = malloc(sizeof(tchar*) * 3);

// the first string has length 20 (+ 1 for null terminator)
errors[0] = malloc(sizeof(tchar) * 21);

// the second string has length 30 (+ 1 for null terminator)
errors[1] = malloc(sizeof(tchar) * 31);

// ensure the last is null
errors[2] = 0;

*returnErrors = errors;
```

**NB: The calling function needs to know that SomeFunction has allocated memory and needs to free it.**

Comment: You might want errors = malloc(sizeof(tchar*) * 3) so you can stick a null terminator in errors[2] to indicate "no more strings."

Answer (score 2):

Are you *implementing* somefunction or *calling* somefunction?

If you are calling somefunction, it is likely that somefunction will be allocating the memory, so all you need to do is pass it a safe place to scribble and clean up afterwards.

```
tchar **theErrors = 0; // a vector of tchar vectors.
somefunction(&theErrors); 
if (theErrors) {
  // use the error values
  // free the memory somehow - this is for a null-terminated convention
      tchar **victim = theErrors;
      while (*victim) delete[](*victim++);
      delete[] theErrors;
}
```

Note: I'm using 0 and delete[] instead of NULL and free because the tag says c++.

Comment: My guess is that the function returns the number of NULL-terminated strings allocated into theErrors array.

Comment: I imagined the function would return an HRESULT, with S_OK, S_FALSE, E_FAIL, E_NOT_IMPLEMENTED etc.

This problem reminds me why I prefer ...
  
    somefunction( std::vector<std::string> > &);

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what "somefunction" is expecting. You have to investigate on this !

It may be expecting a pointer to a fixed-size array of dimension 2, or a regular array of dimension 3, or ???

In the cases i mentionned, code could look like

```
tchar errors[SIZE1][SIZE2];
somefunction( &errors );
```

or

```
tchar errors[SIZE1][SIZE2][SIZE3];
somefunction( errors );
```

Comment: Or probably dozens of other possibilities.  It is completely impossible to know what is expected without documentation (or source) for `somefunction`.

Comment: Right. But I figured simply answering "It depends" would not be of much use ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to allocate the
>   memory for the returnErrors parameter?

The question is too generic and cannot be answered in the general case. Following is just an example of a possible code snippet that calls it.

```
tchar foo;
tchar * p_foo = &foo;
tchar ** pp_foo = &p_foo;
tchar *** ppp_foo = &pp_foo;
somefunction(ppp_foo);
```

Just a comment: I would consider your function signature unsafe and thus a code smell even if it had one star less.

Also, note:

- A pointer is never an array. It is a
  variable which contains the value of
  a memory address, or NULL.
- The  address that a pointer contains
  doesn't always correspond to the
  starting address of an array. int **
  p is not always refering to the
  starting address of an int[][].
- A pointer whose value contains the
  starting address of an array is not
  the best way to pass this array as a
  function parameter. Instead, a reference to the array type can be used.
- An array is usually not the best way to contain a set of related values in C++. std::vector and other STL containers should be considered. (However your question has two languages, C and C++, as tags; of course this only applies to the latter possibility. Why the two tags?)

Answer (score 0):

The triple pointer does not make **any** sense if you don't already have a construct of that type. I would rather recommend using a class - or at least a standard container. But if you must know, it's as simple as

```
tchar ***pointer = (tchar***) malloc(sizeof(tchar**) * amount);
```

Comment: I think you have one * missing. It should instead be (tchar***) malloc(... .

Comment: Just one more thing. Remove the cast and ensure that stdlib.h is included.

Answer (score 0):

There are two use cases for a funciton like your someFunction() that I would use.

**For initialization:**

```
{
    tchar **returnErrors;

    initErrors(tchar &returnErrors);
    /* now returnErrors has a place in memory*/
}

int initErrors(tchar ***returnErrors)
{
    *returnErrors = malloc(sizeof(tchar *) * SIZE1)

     for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
         (*returnErrors)[i] = malloc(sizeof(tchar) * SIZE2);

    /*add checks for malloc failures*/
}
```

**Array passing to a function:**

```
{
    returnErrors[SIZE1][SIZE2][SIZE3];

    someFunciton(returnErrors);
}

int someFunciton(tchar ***returnErrors)
{
    /*assuming that this is a valid index*/
    tchar x = returnErrors[1][1][1]; 
    /*return errors is used as a triple array*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend agree with [tlholaday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540822/allocating-memory-for-triple-pointer/540892#540892)'s guess, with the modification that the function likely returns the number of errors it allocates.

```
tchar **theErrors = 0; // a vector of tchar vectors.
int nErrors = somefunction(&theErrors); 
if (nErrors > 0) {
     for (int i = 0; i < nErrors; ++i)
     {
         printf(theErrors[i]);
         free(theErrors[i]);
     }
     free(theErrors);
}
```

Note that whether you use free or delete[] will depend on how the memory was allocated in the first place.