# Is there any way to take array size from user in c++?

Tags: c++

i want to know if there is a way to take size of a dimentional array from user?
for example for size of a matrix i have tried to definition a pointer,and after takeing size of matrix make memory.
this is:  `

```
void getMatrixSize(&int,&int);  
void makeMatrix(int **mat,int,int);  
void getMatrixData(int **mat,int,int);  

int matrixRow,matrixColumn;  
int **A=NULL;  

int main()  
{  
   int row,column;  
   getMatrixSize(row,column);  
   makeMatrix(A,row,column);  
   getMatrixData(A,row,column);  
}  
getMatrixSize(int &row,int &column)  
{  
   cout<<"Enter matrix row:";  
   cin>>matrixRow;  
   row=matrixRow;  
   cout<<"Enter matrix column:";  
   cin>>matrixColumn;  
   column=matrixColumn;  
}  
makeMatrix(int**mat,int row,int column)  
{  
   int i=0;  
   mat=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*row);  
   if(mat==NULL)  
   {  
      cout<<"Error in getting memory";  
      exit(1);  
   }  
   for(i=0;i<row;i++)  
   {  
      mat[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int))*column);  
      if(mat[i]==NULL)  
      {   
         cout<<"Error in getting memory";  
         exit(1);  
      }  
   }  
}  
void makeMatrixData(int**mat,int row,int column)  
{  
   int i,j;  
   for(i=0;row>i;i++)  
   {  
      for(j=0;column>j;j++)  
      {  
         printf("m[%d][%d]=",i+1,j+1)  
         cin>>mat[i][j];  
      }  
   }  
}
```

the program don't give any error but when i run it, it don't work. when i checked the debuge i realized that it take memory for mat not for A.
this was my idea and didn't find anyway to make it work.do we have any way for take size of a dimentional array from user?

Comment: I'm no grammar cop, and I understand there are many here for whom English is a second language, but the spelling and grammar errors here put me on wild monkey tilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than your use of cin and cout, your code reads like C, not C++.

There is no notion of the size of an array in C++. The way that you're doing it, you'll have to keep track of it manually, so if you plan to write matrix code in C++, I would suggest that you implement Matrix as a class, that you seriously consider using a prepackaged container for your values (vector of vectors is fine, but you can also use a single vector, a single valarray, a single scoped array from boost) instead of managing memory on your own (unless this is the objective of the exercise, and then I'd suggest that you use new and delete instead of malloc and release).

The reason that I'm suggesting that you use prepackaged containers is because today, you should not have to worry about manual memory management in C++ anymore (a lot of people who complain about memory leaks being too easy to create in C++ don't realize this). That is what containers and smart pointers exist for.

If you're wondering about how to use a single array, a single valarray or vector, read up on valarray and slices. That will point you in the right direction.

Finally, if you're writing C++, don't do an exit(1); you should throw an exception (which by the way, is what you'll get by using prepackaged containers or the new operator).

Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a vector of vectors and passing that around by reference?

`std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat(rows, std::vector(cols, 0));` ought to initialize a matrix to all zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

`mat` is a local variable on stack. You better use return value to pass the allocated pointer, but if you want to pass it through parameters - you need to use references:

```
void makeMatrix(int **&mat,int,int);
```

or
'void makeMatrix(int ***mat,int,int);' and pass &A (and do `*mat =` inside).

Comment: It is still April 1, but `***` in C++? Please!

Comment: @Bo - as ugly and un-recommended as it may be, it is still a valid code. The person is obviously trying to learn pointers, references, and all that stuff. If you have other suggestions - add an answer, don't patronize.

Comment: @Bo: Example of triple pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540822/allocating-memory-for-triple-pointer

Comment: @littleadv - I might sound patronizing, sorry, but the number of questions here trying to "optimize" using `void**` is pretty high. Even if using `***` is the answer to the question, that only shows that the question is wrong. Mark B has already given my answer.

Comment: @Bo: Not sure what that means, but OK

Answer (score 0):

i just have found a way with memory allocation.
only need that make a type and then address it's variable in the function.like this:

```
typedef int mymatrix;  
void makeMatrix(mymatrix &mat,int,int);
```

and in main need to definition a pointer and put the pointer in function:

```
int **A;
makeMatrix(A,row,column);
```

so it's possible to take size of dimetional array from user.